# STM32 with encoder

Tags: stm32, encoder, hal

I'm using stwinkt1 board connected to encoder to timer 3.
I want to get a interrupt every time that the encoder count is 300, so the code in the interrupt is:

```
void  TIM3_IRQHandler(void){
    // do things here

    //reset the encoder so ill start counting again
    __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&encoderTimer, 0);
    //clear the interrupt
    HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&encoderTimer);
}
```

but no matter how i define the encoder I get a interrupt each pulse- this is useless and consumes CPU without any reason.
this is how I define the encoder & start it:

```
void Init_Encoder_TIM(void){
    TIM_Encoder_InitTypeDef Config = {0};
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef MasterConfig = {0};

    //define the encoder clock
    encoderTimer.Instance = TIM_ENCODER;
    encoderTimer.Init.Prescaler = 0;
    encoderTimer.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    encoderTimer.Init.Period = 0xFFFF;
    encoderTimer.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    encoderTimer.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
    Config.EncoderMode = TIM_ENCODERMODE_TI1;
    Config.IC1Polarity = TIM_ICPOLARITY_RISING;
    Config.IC1Selection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
    Config.IC1Prescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
    Config.IC1Filter = 0;
    Config.IC2Polarity = TIM_ICPOLARITY_RISING;
    Config.IC2Selection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
    Config.IC2Prescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
    Config.IC2Filter = 0;
    if (HAL_TIM_Encoder_Init(&encoderTimer, &Config) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    MasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    MasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&encoderTimer, &MasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    HAL_TIM_Encoder_Start_IT(&encoderTimer, TIM_CHANNEL_ALL);
}
```

I tried to set the prescaler to 300 it didnt work.
I tried to set the Period to 300 it didnt work as well.
I tried to set the CCR3 manually to 300 and activate the interrupt channel and it didnt work as well.

To be clear- The interrupt works, I get interrupt but for each encoder pulse instead of every 300 pulses.

Hope you will know how to help me
Itay

Comment: You might have better luck in the electronics stackexchange. Microcontroller topics are more common there. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What about other direction?